# Erro não identificado no Jquery

Tags: jquery

Esse erro ocorreu num script meu, porém no meu script não tem essa quebrada de linha que o erro está mostrando.

A descrição do erro é exatamente essa:

```
Uncaught Syntax Error: Unexpected Token ILLEGAL
```

Alguém sabe dizer exatamente o porquê desse erro?

[image: Uncaught Syntax Error: Unexpected Token ILLEGAL]

O erro está acontecendo no append.

```
           $(function () {
                $("body").on("click",".voltar", function(){
                    $("#fotos").animate({height: 'toggle'});
                    $("#albuns").animate({height: 'toggle'});
                });  
                $("body").on("click", ".album", function () {
                    $("#albuns").animate({height: 'toggle'});
                    $.ajax({
                        method: 'POST',
                        url: '../codes/album.php',
                        data: {
                            id : $(this).attr('data-id')
                        },
                        success: function (result) {
                            var retorno = JSON.parse(result);
                            $("#fotos").css("display","initial");                            
                            $("#fotos").empty();          
                            $(retorno).each(function(key, value){$("#fotos").append("<div class='col-lg-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-xs-6 center'><img class='img' src=" + retorno[key].URL + "><br /><small>" + retorno[key].NOME + "</small></div>");})
                            $("#fotos").append("<a class='btn btn-default voltar'>Voltar</a>");
                        } // fim success
                    }); // fim ajax                          
                });
            })
```

Um detalhe que esqueci de acrescentar, é que no **servidor Linux** os meus códigos anteriores e os que foram sugestionados não apresentam erro nenhum, até porque testei e funciona bem. Mas no **servidor Windows**, no qual preciso desse código, é que está apresentando esses erros.

Comment: Poste a parte do seu código que está com erro, fica mais fácil (e possível) identificar.

Comment: só um momento que o farei

Comment: isso mesmo, no meu código, o append está na mesma linha, já no console não está

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consegui resolver, mas foi na base do teste, não entendi bem o porquê resolveu, mas vamos lá:

O código agora:

```
$(function () {
                $("body").on("click",".voltar", function(){
                    $("#fotos").animate({height: 'toggle'});
                    $("#albuns").animate({height: 'toggle'});
                });  
                $("body").on("click", ".album", function () {
                    $("#albuns").animate({height: 'toggle'});
                    $.ajax({
                        method: 'POST',
                        url: '../codes/album.php',
                        data: {
                            id : $(this).attr('data-id')
                        },
                        success: function (result) {
                            var retorno = JSON.parse(result);
                            $("#fotos").css("display","initial");                            
                            $("#fotos").empty();          
                            var html = "";
                                $(retorno).each(function(key, value) {
                                  html += "\<div class='col-lg-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-xs-6 center'>";
                                  html += "<img class='img' src=" + retorno[key].URL + " /><br />";
                                  html += "<small>" + retorno[key].NOME + "</small>";
                                  html += "\</div\>";
                                  });
                                html += "<a class='btn btn-default voltar'>Voltar</a>";
                                $("#fotos").append(html);
                        } // fim success
                    }); // fim ajax                          
                });
            })
```

Notem que na linha do último erro estava assim antes:

```
html += "</div>";
```

Apenas acrescentei uma contrabarra dentro da tag:

```
 html += "</div\>";
```

E funcionou corretamente.

Se alguém entendeu o porquê disso, **explique por favor,** pois apesar de ter resolvido o problema, **quero entender bem o que aconteceu**, sem contar que isso pode ajudar a resolver outros problemas futuros com maior rapidez. Será útil para mim e para quem ver essa pergunta.

Answer (score 8):

O javascript é sensível a quebra de linha, você não pode quebrar linhas no meio de uma string delimitada por aspas, a não ser que você termine a linha com o caractere `\`, que ignorará a interpretação do próximo caractere, no caso a quebra de linha.

Exemplo:

```
var stringLegal = "Essa\
 string\
 é\
 aceitável";
var stringIlegal = "Essa
 aqui
 não"; //dispara Unexpected Token Illegal
```

Comment: mas então... eu queria saber onde ali estou fazendo essa quebrada, deixei tudo numa mesma linha... Acabei de tirar o <br /> e também não funcionou.

Comment: Olha, o <br> não tem nada a ver, ele é quebra de linha interpretada pelo html e não pelo javascript. Se após você tirar a quebra de linha ainda não estiver funcionando, muito provavelmente o  seu navegador está guardando um cache do arquivo anterior. Eu fiz um teste com o trecho de código que você postou aqui e funcionou corretamente, tente por favor limpar o seu cache ou utilizar um outro navegador e nos dê um retorno.

Comment: vlw vou fazer aqui

Answer (score 5):

Ao invés de fazer o `append` dentro do `loop`, faça isso apenas uma vez após finalizar o loop.

```
var html = "";
$(retorno).each(function(key, value) {
  html += "<div class='col-lg-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-xs-6 center'>";
  html += "<img class='img' src=" + retorno[key].URL + " /><br />";
  html += "<small>" + retorno[key].NOME + "</small>";
  html += "</div>";
});

html += "<a class='btn btn-default voltar'>Voltar</a>";
$("#fotos").append(html);
```

**Por que fazer isso?**

- Organização: fica mais fácil você ler o código, note que separei em linhas que "simulam" uma identação.
- Desempenho: chamar o `append` apenas uma vez é mais eficiente.
- E por fim, você tem a certeza que sua `string` está sem erros.

Comment: Coloquei desse jeito que você recomendou, só que agora está dando um erro lá no finalzinho dessa linha: html += "</div>";  Ele está colocando uma tag <p> ali no final dela, não entendi bem. Tenho que acrescentar um detalhe na pergunta, talvez possa nos ajudar a identificar o erro melhor

Comment: Não entendi o que você quis dizer @DiChrist. Dentro da `string` está sendo adicionado um valo que você não adicionou? Isso não é possível. Em algum momento você adiciona a tag `p` no seu código? Se sim, o erro deve estar nesse local.

Comment: é cara, em nenhum momento adiciono nada, uma coisa que percebi foi a seguinte, ele estava dando erro na primeira atribuição do html nessa linha: html += "<div class='col-lg-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-xs-6 center'>";

Então eu coloquei uma contrabarra depois da aspa aí ficou assim:
html += "\<div class='col-lg-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-xs-6 center'>";

Aí parou de sinalizar o erro ali. Tentei fazer o mesmo nessa linha que está dando erro agora, mas não tá dando certo. Não entendi o porque dessa tag <p> estar aparecendo.

Comment: depois dá uma olhada na resposta que postei

Answer (score 2):

Bem, se funciona em um servidor Linux e em um Windows não, é provável que o problema seja charset. Tente apagar essa parte do código e readicioná-la manualmente em um editor diferente no SO Windows. Isso ocorre em muitos casos porque o fim de linha no DOS é `\r\n` enquanto no Unix `\n`, pode ser que nessa troca de servidores tenha sido adicionada uma quebra de linha em modo Unix que não é reconhecida pelo seu editor no Windows, porém seu navegador a interprete.

Comment: depois dá uma olhada na resposta que postei